# Install software in Android Studio

Tags: android, arcgis, android-studio

Today I downloaded and installed the Android Studio and I have already a problem...

I'm programming an Android app that uses an `ArcGIS API for Android`.

To use this API in Eclipse, we need to use the `Install New Software`, and then choose an .zip file to install it...

Is there is any way in Android Studio that "simulates" the "Install New Software" of Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's "Install New Software..." feature installs Eclipse Plugins, not project libraries or other more portable pieces of software.

As far as I know, IntelliJ and the Android Studio do not support and do not plan to support Eclipse Plugins.

Comment: Well it seems i'm stuck to Eclipse.